# How to start BackgroundWorker after CancelAsync

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls, backgroundworker

I'm using backgroundworker in UserControls which I'm loading into panels by a button click.
I hit CancelAsync BW in one UC, then I go to another UC. When I want to return to previous UС (where I've canceled BW) I always enter RunWorkerCompleted event.

I've tried to re-initialize BW in UC constructor:

```
bgrWorker = new BackgroundWorker
        {
            WorkerSupportsCancellation = true,
            WorkerReportsProgress = true
        };

        bgrWorker.DoWork += DoWork;
        bgrWorker.ProgressChanged += ProgressChanged;
        bgrWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += RunWorkerCompleted;

        btnStop.Click += StopWorker;
```

But it doesn't work.

Code of DoWork event:

```
System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.For(0, _list.Count, num =>
            {
                if (bgrWorker.CancellationPending)
                {
                    e.Cancel = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    _splittedList.Add(FindMiddle.Find(_list[num], 20));
                    bgrWorker.ReportProgress(0);
                }
            });
```

Comment: If you've got two different BackgroundWorkers, they *should* be independent. It's not clear what's going on - but if you could write a short but *complete* program, it would be a lot clearer.

Comment: They are independent. I have several UCs with one BW in each.

Comment: Then cancelling one should have no effect on another... but once you *have* cancelled one, you would have to recreate it, I suspect.

Comment: I've tried this: _I've tried to re-initialize BW in UC constructor_

Comment: Yes, I read that - but when you "return to previous UC" that's presumably *not* calling the constructor again, is it? (The idea of *redoing* something in a constructor is strange to start with.) Your question is still very unclear in terms of what you're doing - again, a short but complete program would help a great deal.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I forgot that I'm not creating new UCs, I'm using existing. So I moved re-initialization to another place and it works. Please, post your comment as an answer so I could mark it. Thank you!

Comment: Done, thanks. Glad it was simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(As instructed in comments :)

When you return to the previous user control, that won't rerun the constructor - so if you need to reinitialize the `BackgroundWorker` at that point, you need to move the initialization code into a method that can be run at the appropriate time.